# How can I use DB first approach in .NET Core 6?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-6.0

I try to use Entity Framework in a minimal API running in a .NET Core 6 project. As far as I understand I should run `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold xxxx` which I do, I don't get any errors but no models are added to my project.

Can someone please explain how I can use DB first approach with CRUD functionality?

Comment: Maybe try EF Core Power Tools?

Comment: First: Design your database and create tables
Second: Create entity classes for each table
Use this link:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: What version of EF do you use ?

Comment: EF Core Power Tools helped me (thanks @ErikEJ, I just had to add the override OnConfiguring and add the connectionstring then it worked. I use EF 6.04.

Comment: This question lacks info on what exactly was tried and is too broad anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This sample command should work

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ShopDB" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models
```

Comment: I needed to use "dotnet-ef"

Comment: also data source is missing a slash (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

Answer (score 0):

You should use Frameworks as Microsoft.NETCore.App

Packages from NuGet Package Manager

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Now you can run the command:

> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=10.10.10.123;Database=Testdb; user id=sa;
> password=Sa1234" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir
> Models -Context TestDBContext -Tables employee

Answer (score 0):

I just went through that exercise, and followed the following steps.

First Using nuget package manager install the following: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Then run the following in package manager console:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Trusted_Connection=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Entities
```

I did get the error below

```
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.14' is older than that of the runtime '6.0.8'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw
```

Then I run the following script in package manager console:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm using *EF Core Power Tools*, too. Sometimes, EF Core Power Tools gives errors about failure and you can see what you are missing. Definitely should be given a chance...

At the MS EF learn website, they said that *"Generates code for a DbContext and entity types for a database. In order for this command to generate an entity type, the database table must have a primary key"*. Also there are a lot of informations.

Rarely, we can forget to add keys to our tables. Tables' fields' types maybe incompatible.

[EF Core | MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).